# Does mod_ssl 2.8.31 work with Apache 2.2?

Tags: apache, https, openssl, http-authentication, mod-ssl

I'm trying to setup a mod_ssl - Apache server for authentication purpose. I just downloaded the latest mod_ssl package (2.8.31) and the CHANGE document says it's only been upgraded to Apache 1.3.41. However, 1.3.x is no longer maintained.

Should I stick with the older version of the Apache just because mod_ssl said so or should I upgrade to Apache 2.2?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Z.Zen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_ssl` is included in the Apache source distribution now - you don't have to obtain it separately.

Comment: Thanks Caf! So all I have to do is to download the openssl package, right?

Comment: @Z.Zen: That's right, you'll need the openssl development files to compile mod_ssl (depending on your OS, they may be distributed in a separate package to the openssl runtime files).

Comment: The release note of Apache 2.2.15 says "this release was updated to reflect the OpenSSL Project's release 0.9.8m of the openssl library". Do u think it's safe to use openssl 1.0.0a (the latest) when apache is only updated to 0.9.8m? Thanks!

Comment: @Z.Zen: That's a question you might need to ask on the apache mailing list for a definite answer, but I'm quietly confident it would be fine.